# ¿Por qué no se despliega mi menú hamburguesa?

Tags: javascript, html

El menú se despliega perfectamente cuando le doy clic al botón del menú hamburguesa pero cuando subo el proyecto a Github, también funciona perfectamente el botón hamburguesa cuando le doy clic pero no se despliega el menú.

¿Alguien podría echarme una mano, por favor, para que se despliegue el menú cuando le dé un clic al botón hamburguesa?

En el siguiente enlace de Github pueden ver el problema con claridad:

- https://arturomolo.github.io/Trading/

P.D.: No hagan mucho caso a los comentarios aclaratorios que dejo en el código. Soy un novato en esto.

Código HTML:

```
<header>
        <div class="menu_bar">
            <a href="#" class="bt-menu"><span class="icon-menu"></span>
                <button class="hamburger hamburger--collapse" type="button">
                    <span class="hamburger-box"><span class="hamburger-inner"></span></span>
                </button>
            </a>

            <a href="index.html" class="logo">
                <img src="logo.png" alt="logotipo de ANG" width="70">
            </a>
        </div>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="curso-inicial.html">CURSO INICIAL</a></li>
                <li><a href="curso-avanzado.html">CURSO AVANZADO</a></li>
                <li><a href="sistema-trading.html">MI SISTEMA DE TRADING</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/arturofxtrader/">INSTAGRAM</a></li>
           </ul>
        </nav>

        <div class="cabecera">
            <div class="enlaces-cabecera">
            <a class="cursos" href="cursos.html">CURSOS</a>
            <a class="sistema" href="sistema-trading.html">MI SISTEMA DE TRADING</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Código Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(main); //Es decir, cuando el documento o función main esté ready, es decir, cuando toda nuestra página se haya cargado primero//

var contador = 1; //Antes de crear la función main añadimos una variable contador igual a 1//

function main(){ //Función main//
    $('.bt-menu').click(function(){ //Es decir, cuando haga click en el botón menu_bar pasará lo siguiente que vamos a escribir//
        //$('nav').toggle();//
        //Si usamos tooggle el menu aparece desplegado nada mas entrar en la web. Lo haremos de otra manera. Nos vamos a estilos css y en header nav añadimos left:-100%;//
        //Añadimos un condicional://
        if(contador == 1){
            $('nav').animate({
                left: '0'
            });
            contador = 0;
        } else {
            contador = 1;
            $('nav').animate({
                left: '-100%'
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Hoja de estilos CSS:

```
header nav{
        max-width:1000px;
        margin:1.25rem auto;
        background:#000;
        width:20%;/*Para que no ocupe toda la anchura de la ventana*/
        height:100%;
        margin:0;
        position:fixed;
        left:-100%; /*El menu desplegable se escuentra escondido en la izquierda nada mas entrar en la web*/
    }
    
    .menu_bar{ /*Editamos la barra que contiene el botón del menú*/
        display:block; /*Para que aparezca ya que antes escondimos la barra con display none*/
        width:100%;
        background:#ccc;
        display:flex; /*Para que abarca el 100% del ancho de la ventana*/
        justify-content:space-between;
        padding:auto; /*Para hacer más grande la barra*/
        background:#000; /*Igual que el color de la barra del menu para que todo parezca un solo elemento*/
        color:#fff;
        text-decoration:none; /*Para quitar el subrayado de la palabra Menu*/
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:1.56rem;
        -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
        box-sizing:border-box;
    }
    .menu_bar .bt-menu{
        margin-left:0.6rem;
    }
```

Comment: ¿Puedo hacerte un pull request con las modificaciones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías concentrar el código que gestiona la pulsación del botón "hamburguesa", de modo que esa funcionalidad deberías agregarla en el código que activa o desactiva el botón ([ver aquí en el repositorio](https://github.com/ArturoMolo/Trading/blob/gh-pages/menu.js)):

```
var hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
// On click
hamburger.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Toggle class "is-active"
    hamburger.classList.toggle("is-active");
    // Do something else, like open/close menu
    /* Aquí hacemos que tenga o no la clase "active" */
    document.querySelector("nav").classList.toggle("active");
});
```

Ahora puedes tener en la hoja de estilos una clase "active" que realice la transición de `-21%` a `0px`:

```
nav {
    transition: left 1s;
    left: -21%;
}

nav.active {
    left: 0;
}
```

NOTA: Deberás cambiar el estilo de `header nav` para que `left: -21%` (ya que tiene `width: 20%`). Si pones `-100%` hará una transición desde una posición demasiado a la izquierda y parecerá que tarda un tiempo en reaccionar.

Puedes ver la versión corregida en línea desde el fork que hice de tu repositorio:

- https://ojgarciab.github.io/Trading/

---

He creado un **pull request** en github para que, si lo aceptas, arregles este problema:

- https://github.com/ArturoMolo/Trading/pull/2

Detalles del commit:

- https://github.com/ArturoMolo/Trading/pull/2/commits/8b3a0daa852404e85c64b196ec3937a990e15d43

[image: Detalles del commit]

Comment: Muchísimas gracias @OscarGarcia. Ha funcionado perfectamente. De hecho ahora con la transition:left 1s; me gusta más como aparece y desaparece el menú. Eres un crack! Gracias

Comment: ¡De nada! Un placer :D recuerda que en `transition` puedes indicar qué atributos CSS quieres animar. Yo he puesto `left` pero podrías poner también `opacity`, por ejemplo, haciendo un efecto de aparecer y desvanecerse además del desplazamiento. Te recomiendo que aprendas a hacer las cosas sin usar **jQuery**, crea malos hábitos y su creación fue debido a la enorme diversidad de implementación de los estilos CSS, XHR, etc. Hoy en día prácticamente todos los navegadores gráficos (dentro de soporte, Internet/Windows Explorer ya no está soportados por Microsoft, Edge sí) son compatibles entre sí.